# Unable to parse fields available within page source from a webpage

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script in python to parse two fields from a webpage. The fields I'm interested in are javascript encrypted. However, they are available in page source within json array. The following script can produce that json array from that page but I can't dig out the desired fields out of it.

> Once you navigate to that page, all you need to do is click on this tab `Quarterly` to see the fields how it is shown here:

[image]

[Webpage link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL)

I've tried so far:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'link has been given above'

res = requests.get(url)
data = re.findall(r'root.App.main[^{]+(.*);',res.text)[0]
jsoncontent = json.loads(data)
print(jsoncontent)
```

PS I already know how to get them using selenium, so browser simulator is not an option I would like to comply with.

Comment: I'm trying to work this out. Your current script isn't returning valid json, but the json on the page is valid. You can use a tool like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to traverse the tree and figure out where your data might be.

Comment: In my case the script does really return valid json response. Strange!!

Comment: Ah it was an issue with quotes and how jsonlint likes to deal with it. Anyway, answered below, jsonview.stack.hu was necessary to drill down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quarterly data is deep in the dict, but you can get it like this:

`jsoncontent['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['earnings']['financialsChart']['quarterly']`

Returns:
`[{'date': '3Q2018', 'revenue': {'raw': 62900000000, 'fmt': '62.9B', 'longFmt': '62,900,000,000'}, 'earnings': {'raw': 14125000000, 'fmt': '14.12B', 'longFmt': '14,125,000,000'}}, {'date': '4Q2018', 'revenue': {'raw': 84310000000, 'fmt': '84.31B', 'longFmt': '84,310,000,000'}, 'earnings': {'raw': 19965000000, 'fmt': '19.96B', 'longFmt': '19,965,000,000'}}, {'date': '1Q2019', 'revenue': {'raw': 58015000000, 'fmt': '58.02B', 'longFmt': '58,015,000,000'}, 'earnings': {'raw': 11561000000, 'fmt': '11.56B', 'longFmt': '11,561,000,000'}}, {'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': {'raw': 53809000000, 'fmt': '53.81B', 'longFmt': '53,809,000,000'}, 'earnings': {'raw': 10044000000, 'fmt': '10.04B', 'longFmt': '10,044,000,000'}}]`

And then to get to your quarter, you can loop through that:

```
quarter = jsoncontent['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['earnings']['financialsChart']['quarterly']
for q in quarter:
    print(q)  # print all quarters
    if q['data'] == "1Q2019":
        print(q)  # print the quarter you want
```

Comment: It throws this error `quarter = jsoncontent['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['earnings']['financialsChart']['quarterly']
KeyError: 'earnings'`

Comment: You're missing `QuoteSummaryStore` in what you pasted

Comment: same here `print(jsoncontent['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['earnings']['financialsChart']['quarterly'])
KeyError: 'earnings'`

Comment: It's still working on my end - perhaps re-run your initial script to reset jsoncontent? Also, print out `jsoncontent['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']` and see what that contains? (jsonviewer.stack.hu might be easier)